# MS Access VBA - Append String to Text Box, Reappend when updated

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to creating a MS Access form, where a user would input comments in a text box (Input), and the text would be appended each time to a summary box which would be greyed out and is non editable.

[image]

The Input comments will be auto formatted to include the date timestamp and username using the following code:

```
Private Sub IncidentDescriptionInput_AfterUpdate()
    Dim Output As String
    Output = Me!IncidentDescriptionInput.Value
    Output = Output & " " & Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yy") & "/" & Format(Now(), "hh:nn") & "/" & Environ("UserName") & ";"
    Me!IncidentDescriptionInput.Value = Output
End Sub
```

Comment: And what's your exact question? What did you code already to try to fulfill that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code already demonstrates the techniques required to achieve your goal:

- Updating the value held by a form control as part of the event handler for the `AfterUpdate` event. You already do this in your existing code with `Me!IncidentDescriptionInput.Value = Output`
- Retrieving the existing value of a form control for concatenation with another string. You already do this in your existing code with `Output = Me!IncidentDescriptionInput.Value`
- Concatenating the existing value of a form control with another string. You already do this in your existing code with `Output = Output & " " & Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yy") ...`

And so, you already have the building blocks required to achieve the desired result.

Assuming that the summary box is called `IncidentDescriptionSummary`, then the code might be modified to something like:

```
Private Sub IncidentDescriptionInput_AfterUpdate()
    Dim Output As String
    Output = IncidentDescriptionInput & " " & Format(Now(), "dd-mmm-yy\/hh:nn\/") & Environ("UserName") & ";"
    IncidentDescriptionInput = Output
    IncidentDescriptionSummary = IncidentDescriptionSummary & vbCrLf & Output
End Sub
```